# Need guidence about ldapadd

Tags: ldap

I am using centos 5.1 for configuring ldap server to authenticate my windowx xp users.In one of the tutorial I read  that they are populating ldap with ese lines.

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/ldap/schema/cosine.ldif
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/ldap/schema/nis.ldif
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/ldap/schema/inetorgperson.ldif
```

Kindly just guide me that that these lines actually do ?

Answer (score 0):

They add the schema informations listed in the respective files to the `cn=config` namespace of your LDAP server which is used to configure it.

With the `-Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:///`  part, you tell `ldapadd` to talk directly to the LDAP server and authenticate based on your user ID (usually configured to allow access by uid=0, root) and not to use the LDAP protocol via network for this.

These schemas are the description of the valid fields and field types for your directory.

Answer (score 0):

Those lines just add couple of LDAP schemas to your LDAP server so it can be configured for authenticating Windows users.

I think it was you who I yesterday told about complexities of configuring LDAP + Samba + Windows authentication and how there are books written about the topic .... starting to believe me? :)